# Dealing with 503 or other error on third party page via javascript in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Wrote a very simple Chrome extension with Javascript to refresh a third party page every 750 ms until a certain element becomes available:

```
if (document.getElementById("abc123") != null) {
    document.getElementById("abc123").submit();
    }
else {
    window.setInterval(function() {document.location.reload(true);}, 750);
    }
```

Ran in to an issue with the execution when the script hit a 503 error.  For some reason, the 503 error page did not trigger the else condition, and the script stopped.  Any suggestions on how I can modify the script to provide a solution for such an issue?

Comment: my guess is that you're using a `content script`, and since the page wasn't served - the script never ran in the first place, it's not that it stopped. Another thing: use `window.setTimeout()` - which is essentially a countdown (what you need). `setInterval` triggers the function repeatedly every X ms. edit: [read more about content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

Comment: Would I wrap all the original code in a window.setTimeout() function?